# NameError: name 'x1' is not defined in California housing data

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhadipml/California-Housing-Price-Prediction/master/housing.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df

#Subset all rows where ocean_proximity is equal to NEAR BAY. Call this variable x1.
df['ocean_proximity'] = df['ocean_proximity'].str.replace('NEAR BAY', 'x1') 

#when I try to print x1, it shows error
print(x1.shape)
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6e7c2a59f460> in <module>()
      1 df['ocean_proximity'] = df['ocean_proximity'].str.replace('NEAR BAY', 'x1') #Subset all rows where ocean_proximity is equal to NEAR BAY. Call this variable x1.
----> 2 print(x1.shape)

NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

Can anyone advise what's the problem?

Comment: Did you mean `print(df.shape)`?

Comment: Seems like you have not defined the `x1` there because `x1` is inside your `df`.

Did you mean:
```x1 = df['df['ocean_proximity'] = 'NEAR BAY'] ```
`x1.shape`

Comment: Yes. I would like to subset all rows where ocean_proximity is equal to NEAR BAY and print the shape, and call this variable x1.

Comment: I just posted an answer. Please check if that works. :))

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call x1 as a variable but in your code x1 is a string in your DataFrame. You can try this code

```
df['ocean_proximity'] = df['ocean_proximity'].str.replace('NEAR BAY', 'x1')
x1 = df[['ocean_proximity']] # to get a DataFrame
print(x1.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subhadipml/California-Housing-Price-Prediction/master/housing.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df

#Subset all rows where ocean_proximity is equal to NEAR BAY. Call this variable x1.
x1 = df[df['ocean_proximity'] == "NEAR BAY"]
```

```
x1.shape
->> (2290, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = df[df['ocean_proximity'] == "NEAR BAY"]

x2 = df[df['ocean_proximity'] == "<1H OCEAN"]

#Make a histogram of x1 with nice titles, axes labels and colored blue.
#Make a histogram of x1 with nice titles, axes labels and colored blue.

import seaborn as sns

kwargs = dict(hist_kws={'alpha':.6},kde_kws={'linewidth':2})

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7),dpi=80)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ba84939e49fe> in <module>()
      1 #plot
      2 kwargs = dict(hist_kws={'alpha':.6},kde_kws={'linewidth':2})
----> 3 plt.figure(figsize=(10,7),dpi=80)

NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

what's the problem with plt?